# Asynchronous OAuth 2 login and token storage in Android application

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am implementing authorization screen in Android application that should use OAuth 2 token.

I retrieve token from server with POST request using Apache HTTP library inside AsyncTask. Then that token must be stored somewhere (in SQLite database, SharedPreferences or somewhere else) to use it in other parts of application (such as file uploading and sending user messages).

The first problem is how to create correct architecture for authorization. I assume that it should be some class SessionManager storing activity context and having method authorizeUser(UserCredentials info) that executes async task, retrieves token from that task, stores token info somewhere and then callbacks activity to make appropriate changes in user interface, but I don't know how to get token from AsyncTask properly.

```
public void authorizeUser(UserCredentials info) {
    if (mListener != null)
        mListener.onAuthorizationRequested();

    Token token = null;

    // TODO: Get token

    if (token != null) {
        // TODO: Store token somewhere
        mListener.onAuthorizationSuccess(new AuthorizationResult(AuthorizationStatus.SUCCESS, "Just success"));
    }
    else {
        mListener.onAuthorizationFailed(new AuthorizationResult(AuthorizationStatus.FAIL, "Just fail"));
    }
}
```

The second problem is how to refresh token automatically when it's expired.

Comment: Have you seen AccountManager docs?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to implement my own token retrieving logic.

Comment: try reading <sdk>/docs//training/id-auth/authenticate.html it should help

Comment: I just want to know best practices in implementation of authorization and token checking, not the API.

Comment: ok you don't have to do anything, its your choice